# If condition what will be in else part?

Tags: conditional-statements

Condition in my program looks like this...

```
  if(Revision_Number>0 || QuoteLink!=null)
   {

   }
  else()
   {

   }
```

So what will the else part act like? will the **else** part be like if(Revision_Number<0 || QuoteLink==null)? What will the else condition look like ?

Comment: It isn't checked, so why does it matter to you? If you really want, it is `!(if_condition)`, but you don't need it.

Comment: You do not always want an `else` condition. In this case, you may not use any `else` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `else` is executed for *all other* cases in which the associated `if` conditionals will not match.

That would, given the a positive expression of of `Revision_Number>0 || QuoteLink!=null` in "if", result in the (negative/inverse) "else" expression being:

```
!(Revision_Number>0 || QuoteLink!=null)
```

Then using [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), where the distribution rules change the `||` to `&&`.

```
!(Revision_Number>0) && !(QuoteLink!=null)
```

And with simplification

```
Revision_Number <= 0 && QuoteLink == null
```

(Note that `!(x > y)` -> `x <= y`, assuming the values are well-ordered; the change in equality is important.)

---

Thus,

```
if(Revision_Number>0 || QuoteLink!=null) {};   
else {};
```

is *generally* equivalent to

```
if(Revision_Number>0 || QuoteLink!=null) {};   
else if (Revision_Number <= 0 && QuoteLink == null) {};
```

However, the former case should be preferred, and implementation details such as side-effects or an odd value like NaN, can affect the results.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing, until and unless you want it to do something... In that case, you can use `else if` statement to be more precise. Also, if you don't need a final else-block, don't write one. it's just senseless to have a block of code (possibly containing just a this is useless-comment) that isn't needed.